# Can Kafka be used as a distribute work queue

Tags: java, apache-kafka, distributed-computing, software-design

I'm considering Kafka to use as a distributed work queue multiple workers can retrieve tasks from. My original design looks as:

```
Work Producer ---> Kafka topic ------worker 1
                                  |
                                  |__worker 2
                                  ...
                                  |__worker n
```

The problems with this design is this:

1. If some worker takes a task from the topic and immediately commits offset then in case of failure the task may not be reprocessed.
2. If some worker takes a task from the topic and commits offset only on finish then other workers may also takes this task and process it. If the task is pretty long lasting then almost all workers will take the same task and process it completely inhibiting the distributing nature.

---

I'm looking for a way "mark" a task in a queue as "in progress" so it's not consumed by anyone else, but offset is not committed (because it may fail and needs reprocessing). Is it possible to implement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If some worker takes a task from the topic and immediately commits offset then in case of failure the task may not be reprocessed.

In that case I recommend to use manual commits and disable the auto.commit.offset configuration of your consumer.

> If some worker takes a task from the topic and commits offset only on finish then other workers may also takes this task and process it. If the task is pretty long lasting then almost all workers will take the same task and process it completely inhibiting the distributing nature.

You could deal with this scenario by designing your topic with partitions and your consumers with a ConsumerGroup. In Kafka, every partition can only be read by one consumer thread within a Consumer Group.

That means, as long as all your consumers (or "workers") belong to the same ConsumerGroup it will **never** be the case that two workers will start reading and processing the same message.

Comment: While I wouldn't disagree with any of this, I wonder if the complexity of Kafka is required for what is, in the end, a relatively simple message distribution task, presumably with low-ish volume? There are many message distribution technologies that could do the same, without the complexity of Kafka. Of course, if you already _have_ Kafka, it makes sense to use it.

Comment: Yes, I can only support what @KevinBoone is saying. I guess it depends in the end on the available alternatives and the volume of tasks/workers which is difficult to judge from the information given in the question.

Comment: _every partition can only be read by one consumer thread within a Consumer Group_ Dont quite understand this. If there are, say, 2 consumers in a group the only one May "aquire" a particular partition and read from it? The other one Will never read?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. If you have 2 consumers within the same group and a topic with only one partition, one consumer will read the other one will be idle the whole time and never read any message. (unless there is a rebalance happening). There is a nice [introduction](https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation.html#intro_consumers) on the Kafka consumers.